# Ultraproduct reflexive

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ultrapowers

Hello I have the following construction: Let $(E,\|\cdot\|_E)$ be a Banach space, $E_n:=E^n$ and $\|x_n\|_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \|x_n(k)\|_E$ for all $x_n=(x_n(1),...,x_n(n))\in E^n$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. My question is whether the ultraproduct $(E_n)_{\mathcal{U}}$ along any (free) ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ is reflexive if $E$ is superreflexive?

Comment: If $E=\mathbb{R}$, then your ultraproduct is an infinite-dimensional AL-space (i.e. a Banach lattice whose norm is additive on the positive cone) and hence not reflexive.